# My phone is blocked

Tags: lock-screen, lumia-925

My phone says I should wait for 21000 minutes to unlock,I don't want to wipe it/reset it I have important information I still need, will it really work after waiting for those minutes?

Comment: That's roughly 2 weeks. If your data is that important, find another phone and wait for two weeks. But after the period, please be sure to enter the correct password to unlock the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Go to here: https://account.microsoft.com/devices and click on "Find my phone". Then click "Lock".  Enter a new Lock code to lock your phone with a code you know. Then go back to the phone to unlock it with the new code. This also overrides the delay. This only works of course if your phone has a working internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you enter proper unlock code.